# Drupal subdirectory muti-site and boost

Tags: drupal

I've been struggling with drupal multi-site for quite some time. Now I'm trying to optimize a big multi-site (subdirectory, not subdomain) and I'm facing an issue with boost module.

Apparently the default subsite works fine with boost; but the rest tells me that rules in *.htaccess* are wrong considering they are in a subdirectory.

What is the proper way to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Checkout here: http://banavoz.com/2010/08/drupal-multisite-boost-cache/

Here blogger has provided htaccess setting which might be useful.

If that doesn't help, then check this: http://drupal.org/project/provision_boost

Comment: thanx for such a quick answer. I'll check those links.

Comment: sorry... I forgot to mention my drupal multi-site is based on drupal 6.20